# How can I reduce the batch_size and the image_shape in the matterport/Mask_RCNN example?

Tags: python, keras

When I run the following code, I get the following error

```
from mrcnn.config import Config

class KangarooConfig(Config):
    # define the name of the configuration
    NAME = "kangaroo_cfg"
    # number of classes (background + kangaroo)
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1
    # number of training steps per epoch
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 131


from mrcnn.model import MaskRCNN

# prepare config
config = KangarooConfig()
config.display()
# define the model
model = MaskRCNN(mode='training', model_dir='./', config=config)
model.keras_model.metrics_tensors = []


# load weights (mscoco) and exclude the output layers
model.load_weights('mask_rcnn_coco.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",  "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"] )
# train weights (output layers or 'heads')
model.train(train_set, test_set, learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, epochs=5, layers='heads' )
```

Error:

> ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Resource
>   exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[400,14,14,256] and
>   type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by
>   allocator GPU_0_bfc

How can I reduce the batch_size and the image_size in this case?

[image: Output of Code]

Comment: I managed to reduce the batch_size by adding the following     
`GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your [Config.py](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/config.py) file and change

```
 IMAGE_MIN_DIM = 800 to 400
 IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 1024 to 512
```

and

```
IMAGES_PER_GPU = 2 to 1
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE = "square" to "none"
```

Comment: using `IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE=None` returned `invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [1,76,100,256] vs. [1,75,100,256]` , but when I removed that line, the rest worked fine. Any reasons for that error ?

Comment: The images used in the in training the models don't have the same size on drive, you have to force some images to have a certain and common size for all images, from the shape you ve posted, it seems that padding is being done(not sure) , try with "none" or "pad64", don't forget the double quotes, and also none is in small caps, i updated my answer